# Narrow a Drawing Tools Window

Tags: plotting, graphics, options, drawing

I used the `Graphics->New Graphic`, then the `Drawing Tools` to create this in my notebook.

[image]

Now, you can see that there is wasted whitespace above and below my line. I tried dragging all the sides and corners, but the effect is the same, What I want to do is narrow the vertical size of the window only, eliminating some whitespace.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can Ctrl+Drag to do clipping style operations.

Comment: @Kuba why not elaborate on the programmatic options? I guess the `Shrinkwrap->True` hack should be applicable here, too.

Comment: @YvesKlett I really don;t like drawing tools :P I just wanted the question to be answered and I would really choose your answer. Feel free to include that way too.

Comment: David, was that what you were after?

Answer (score 2):

You can press down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging to do clipping-style manipulations:

[image]

More convenient might be a programmatic  way, e.g. using:

```
Show[graphics, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

However, this method does not really work well with text (that tends to be cut off), so sometimes a bit of manual dragging might be in order anyway.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you very much.